# mysql select table where number of rows depends on dynamic values in two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table:

```
id | style  | minsize_id | maxsize_id
-------------------------------------
1  | Jacket | 1          |  3
2  | Pant   | 2          |  4
3  | Hoody  | 0          |  3
```

I would like to show an **extra row for each size id** between and including the minsize_id and maxsize_id (sizes can be any integer between 0 and 9), and a new column 'size_id' as follows:

```
id | style  | size_id
----------------------
1  | Jacket | 1
1  | Jacket | 2
1  | Jacket | 3
2  | Pant   | 2
2  | Pant   | 3
2  | Pant   | 4
3  | Hoody  | 0
3  | Hoody  | 1
3  | Hoody  | 2
3  | Hoody  | 3
```

How do I display the table in this way using only MySQL? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would be sorely tempted to handle this kind of thing at the application level - e.g. with a simple PHP loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way this could be achieved is to join this table onto a derived table which contains 10 rows, one for each size.  For example

```
SELECT

    yt.id,
    yt.style,
    sizes.size_id

FROM yourTable AS yt

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 AS size_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS size_id
) AS sizes
ON sizes.size_id BETWEEN yt.minsize_id AND yt.maxsize_id
```

If however you have a table "sizes" with primary key "size_id" then you can just INNER JOIN that instead of this derived table.  Obviously replace `yourTable` and alias `yt` with whatever table name  / alias you desire.

Comment: +1 . . . But I would replace the `union` with `union all` since duplicate elimination is not needed.

Comment: Agreed @Strawberry, a PHP solution would be better. This is just a short term solution.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net - so simple, so fast! And there is a size table so in line with your suggestion I have amended the join to 'INNER JOIN sizes ON sizes.size_id BETWEEN yt.minsize_id AND yt.maxsize_id'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT id, style, size_id
FROM origTable ot
JOIN 
(SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS size_id
 FROM origTable ot1
 CROSS JOIN origTable ot2,
 (SELECT @rownum := -1) r) s
ON ot.minsize_id <= s.size_id AND ot.maxsize_id >= s.size_id
ORDER BY id, style, size_id
```

It may look a little messy at first glance but I'll try and explain:

MySQL doesn't have a `row_number` function like SQL Server does so I'm using a technique [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql?rq=1#answer-1895127) to artificially create this in the subquery (s). To create a lot of row numbers there needs to be a lot of rows in this so you could either choose a different table that already has a lot of rows or as I've done just do a `CROSS JOIN` of your original table - `CROSS JOIN`s generally ends up with a lot of rows. Bit of a hack I know and may have degrading performance if `origTable` becomes large!

We need the row numbers to start at zero and what is selected by the subquery is pre-incremented by 1, hence the initialisation of `@rownum` to `-1`.

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a54494/4).

Comment: Thanks for your ingenious answer, this also did the trick albeit with a lower performance as you suspected.

Comment: Pleasure. The advantages this offers over the other answer is compactness of the query and flexibility if the number of size_ids becomes large. If performance is an issue you could kind of combine the two answers and join on your own table with n rows where n is the maximum difference between minsize_id and maxsize_id.